# trying to understand some js codes from a site

Tags: javascript

```
Ev.DOMit = function (e) {
    e = e ? e : window.event; // e IS passed when using attachEvent though ...

    if (!e.target) {
        e.target = e.srcElement;
    }

    if (!e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault = function () {
            e.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        };
    }

    return e;
};

Ev.getTarget = function (e) {
    e = Ev.DOMit(e);
    var tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.nodeType !== 1) {
        tgt = tgt.parentNode;
    }
    return tgt;
};
```

I saw above code from one js file

Questions:

1.

```
            e.returnValue = false;
            return false;
```

since we already have this line: `e.returnValue = false;`,why we need to have this line here:  `return false;`?

2 .

```
    if (tgt.nodeType !== 1) {
        tgt = tgt.parentNode;
    }
```

what is this line for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `e.returnValue = false;` sets the property returnValue of the function argument. The `return false;` method returns the function with the value of 'false'.
2. My guess is per this - http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp - the function sets the `tgt` (return value) to the `parentNode` for any node except for ELEMENT_NODE

Comment: W3schools is a terrible resource. MDN documents this just as well, and is much more reliable.

Comment: @JanDvorak - provide the equivalent link

Comment: @TobyAllen finding the possible values is easy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType; you even get to see which of those node types are deprecated (W3S hides the fact some of them are). For the nodeValues see, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue. One thing I didn't find is the handy table of summaries of each type, but that's because MDN is a reference site, not a tutorial site. And, frankly, those summaries tell me nothing - they look quite auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about question 1 but I have some view on question 2.

"nodeType" represent the "integer" value of a node, element like "p, div"

will have node type 1 "this is text" will have node type of "3".

code:

```
            if ( tgt.nodeType !== 1 ) {
            tgt = tgt.parentNode; 
            }
```

I guess coder wants to handle the event on "element" like "p, div" tag.

Example:
Let say we have following html code

```
            <p>Text in p</p>
```

So if some event occur on the text "Text in p" inside "p" then also coder want to get target element for the event as "p" not the text inside it "Text in p".
Now think an event of text node "DOMCharacterDataModified", when this event fire the target
element should be "Text in p" but our coder want the target element as "p" tag.

Again this is a view of mine may concrete answer to the question

One useful Links you may like to read

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Not necessary at all.
2. Make sure `tgt` is always an `ElementNode`, even if the event fires on a contained text node.

Comment: (1) is not necessary only in the given context. If this function is called elsewhere, it may make a difference.

Comment: @zaitsman According to the standards, the `preventDefault` method returns nothing. Thus, returning `false` in IE means creating a polyfill with unexpected behaviour.